# Proving that intersection of a collection of σ-algebras on a space X is a σ-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

My proof: Every sigma-algebra in the collection of sigma algebras which contains at least one sigma-algebra contains the empty set and the set X. Because the set containing the set X and the empty set is a trivial sigma algebra, the intersection of a collection of sigma-algebras on a space X is a sigma algebra.

Comment: But it's possible that the intersection is *more than* just $\{\varnothing, X\}$ (although you have explained why the intersection contains these two).

Comment: That doesn't suffice. You have to prove that it is closed under countable unions and relative complements.

Comment: @Stefan, do I have to prove that the intersection of a collection of sigma-algebras is a dynkin system? What's an example of a sigma algebra whose intersection is more than just $\{$ $\emptyset$, $X$ $\}$?

Comment: You have to prove that the intersection of any number of $\sigma$-algebras (on a given space) is a $\sigma$-algebra. (This is stronger than being a Dynkin system.)

Comment: (There are examples of arbitrarily large families of distinct $\sigma$-algebras whose intersection is a non-trivial $\sigma$-algebra. But the only ones I can think of right now refer to uncountable ordinals and hence are likely not helpful to you.)

Comment: @Stefan Does this work?https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Events_is_Event

Comment: No, you need more than that. You need to prove that the intersection is closed under countable unions/intersections, complements and that it contains the empty set.